# Get relationship if the row exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables, `users` and `roles`, where each `user` *can* (but doesn't have to) have a `role`. The relationship exists through `role_id` and `id` from the two tables, respectively.

How can I create an Eloquent query that gets the user's `role` *if the row exists*?

Here is my current query (although it doesn't do what I need):

```
$user = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%abc%')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Try to add `->with('role')` - I don't recall if it adds something regardless of it existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to define a **user->role** relation in your User model:

```
public function role() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

Then you'll be able to load users together with their roles:

```
$users = User::with('role')->where('username', 'LIKE', '%abc%')->get();
```

Fetched users should have their role available in

```
$user->role
```

If they have no role, the value of this attribute will be **NULL**